# Postpone sending activation codes; Creating a user as "Inactive"

Tags: users, emails, activation

I'm finding the user activation process a bit confusing...

I was trying to create a handful of users, but I didn't want to send out the activation emails yet.

I incorrectly assumed if I unchecked "send activation email" when creating, it would create the user and I would be able to send the activation later.

Instead, Craft creates the user as "active" with no password, and the "Resend activation email" isn't available.

At this point I'm stuck, as you can't set a user to inactive. I'm left with these choices:

- having to set a dummy password, require reset, and manually email my users
- email my users the control panel url, and instruct them to click "Forgot password" and enter the same email I've created their user with.

Neither options are great, unless I'm missing something.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good point, not a very good UX there. We’ll have to come up with something better.